# Double calling controller in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have controller with method that does AJAX request:

```
.controller('EditProfileController', ['$scope', '$http') {
   // Do AJAX query here

   // Some methods for update profile
}]);
```

Also I have `$routeProvider` in this **Angular JS** file:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/profile/personal/:type', {
            templateUrl: '/personal.html',
            controller: 'EditProfileController'
    })
}
```

Problem is that when I open page with URL `/profile/personal/:type` it calls again controller `EditProfileController` and calls AJAX method inside.

How I can fix it?

**HTML** code:

```
<div ng-controller="EditProfileController">
   <!-- Here are loaded data from AJAX response
</div>
```

**Solution:**
Problem was in double `ng-view` in template:

```
<div ng-show="isLoaded" ng-view></div>
<div ng-show="!AILoading" ng-view></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove the `ng-controller` directive from the HTML as the router is already taking care of this

Comment: Nice catch, didn't spot the mistake. To add some informations, i really feel that in a clean AngularJS application you should never use the ng-controller directive. All your controllers will be bind by the routing system.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, I need to remove name of controller from routing? If yes, how routeProvider will recognize about controller?

Comment: No, the `ng-controller` in the HTML can go. Sorry, I should have been clearer - answer updated